# How do I rotate part of a video?

Tags: windows-7, video, rotate

I have a similar [problem as this person](https://superuser.com/questions/174035/how-do-i-rotate-video-mov-file-on-windows). Except that I recorded the first 30 seconds in portrait mode, and then decided the next 4 minutes would look better in landscape mode. So now I have a sideways video for the first 30 seconds. Is there a way I can rotate the first 30 seconds to be in landscape mode?

Comment: You'll need to cut the clip from the file, rotate it to the correct way and then splice it back together. One problem with this is that you've recorded it sideways for a bit, so unless your device is at a 1:1 ratio, then it's going to have to be smaller to fit all of the video or zoomed in to keep the  original resolution.