# Iphone landscape video plays as portrait in media players

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, iphone

I have a landscape video taken with iPhone 5 but when it's played in VLC, Windows Media Player or even iTunes it is played back in portrait orientation. If I use VLC settings to rotate the video to landscape it's displayed as a square, not as original 16:9 video. However, when I opened the video in Power Director with intention of rotating it and saving a copy that would play correctly in VLC it was displayed and played back as landscape.
How do I get iPhone videos taken as landscape videos to play as landscape in media players in Windows?

Comment: Your problems are because of the format.  [How do I rotate video (MOV) file on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/174035/how-do-i-rotate-video-mov-file-on-windows).  The answer(s) is slightly dated because of the reference to Qucktime but the underline solution is the same.  You should convert video away from .mov so you can use VLC and WMP

Comment: Open your file in [Mediainfo](http://www.mediaarea.net), and paste the readout (go to View->Text mode). This may be solvable with a tag edit.

Comment: @Mulvya That's what I was thinking since Power Director was playing it back as landscape...

Comment: Used Handbrake with "--rotate=8" option to convert the video to MP4 as landscape. Can't imagine doing that for every video taken with iPhone so unless there is a solution to play back original MOV videos as taken in Windows can't imagine taking any more videos with an iPhone...

Comment: Weird. As per this [bug](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/4666) tracker, VLC should respect the rotation tag.